# Not picking the correct mapping using EcpliseLInk 2.6.7

Tags: java, eclipselink, hibernate-mapping

I have created an employee hbm file with EclipseLink jar 2.6.7 if it is returning Regular_EMP object then it is picking parent class object( contains t) to insert the data in Employee table but if I have used  EclipseLink jar 2.6.5  with Regular_EMP object  it is picking the correct child class Regular_EMP object and properly insert the day in the employee table. why this is odd behavior with EclipseLink jar2.6.7

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<entity-mappings
xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm 
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<access>PROPERTY</access>
<entity class="Employee">
    <table name="EMP" />
    <discriminator-column name="C_TYPE"
        discriminator-type="STRING" />
    <sequence-generator sequence-name="SEQ_EMP"
        name="gen_securisation" allocation-size="1">
    </sequence-generator>
    <attributes>
        <id name="objId" access="FIELD">
            <column name="N__ID" />
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="gen_emp" />
        </id>
        <basic name="level">
            <column name="N_LEVEL" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity exclude-default-mappings="true"
    class="Regular_EMP">
    <table name="EMP" />
    <inheritance strategy="SINGLE_TABLE" />
    <discriminator-value>3</discriminator-value>
    <attributes>
        <basic name="SPI">
            <column name="B_SPI" />
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

While Regular_EMP is subclass of emp.

Comment: The question really doesn't make what you are doing and the behaviour you see very clear. Sounds like you might be calling persist on an instance of "Regular_EMP" and seeing different behaviour based on EclipseLink jar version. But you haven't shown any details so this is a bad guess - the bit you've shown doesn't even indicate what the 'super' class discriminator-value is, and has the inheritance strategy defined in the child subclass, so even the inheritance hierarchy is questionable. Can you add more details and what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Chirs , Thanks for the reply. I have debugged the eclipse link code  and there is an issue. so the discussion is going on . like I need to change the code or they will do it

Comment: I don't understand your comment, as it seems I'm missing a bit of context. What is the issue exactly that you have debugged? Why have you tagged this with hibernate? The orm.xml file you've shown is very incomplete - if you need assistance, we need more information to be able to help.